# Method of Undetermined Coefficients using X's on left hand side

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a couple questions on this question.

The question is asking me to find the general solution to

$$x'' + 6x' + 9x = \cos(2t) + \sin(2t).$$

Solving for the general solution, I got $$Y_c = C_1e^{-3x}+ C_2xe^{-3x}.$$

I was wondering if the fact that the left hand side uses $x$'s instead of $y$'s matters? For almost every question, it uses $y$'s instead of $x$'s.

Also, for $Y_p$, I got $Y_p = A\cos(2t) + B\sin(2t)$.

I ultimately got the answer to be $$C_1e^{-3x}+ C_2xe^{-3x} - (7\cos(2t)/169) +(17\cos(2t)/169),$$ which I do not feel to be correct.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you call your dependent variable. Here $x = x(t).$

Comment: I see thank you. Does my Yp look correct? If so, it must be a computing error

Answer (score 1):

In this problem, $x$ is the dependant variable, and $t$ is the independant variable. It looks like for your homogenous solution, you solved the homogenous ODE

$$y_c''(x)+6y_c'(x)+9y_c(x)=0$$
With the result

$$y_c(x)=C_1e^{-3x}+C_2xe^{-3x}$$

All the work you did in solving this is totally valid, but you renamed both variables for the ODE. Using the original variables from the problem, we get,
$$x_c''(t)+6x_c'(t)+9x_c(t)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x_c(t)=C_1e^{-3t}+C_2te^{-3t}$$

Your $y_p(t)$ is calculated correctly, but again should actually be named $x_p(t)$.

You can then get the final answer by adding $x_c(t)$ and $x_p(t)$.

Comment: So my final answer turns out to be correct, I just need to adjust the variables accordingly? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The complementary solution is $x_c(t)=C_1e^{-3t}+C_2te^{-3t}$. Note: $x$ is the dependent variable and $t$ is the independent variable in this case.

Moreover, the complementary solution is the solution to the following second-order homogeneous differential equation: $$x_c''+6x_c'+9x_c=0.$$ Finally, in order to get the particular solution, one must guess it to be: $$y_p(t)=A\cos(2t)+B\sin(2t)$$ where $A$ and $B$ are to be found using the Method of Undetermined Coefficients.

After substitution and some algebraic manipulation, the equation becomes:

$$(5A+12B)\cos(2t)+(-12A+5B)\sin(2t)=\cos(2t)+\sin(2t)$$

This implies one gets the following system of two equations with two unknowns via Method of Undetermined Coefficients:

1. $5A+12B=1$,
2. $-12A+5B=1$.

Using Cramer’s rule to solve the system, the solution to the system is $A=-7/169$ and $B=17/169$.

This implies the particular solution is $$x_p(t)=-\frac7{169}\cos(2t)+\frac{17}{169}\sin(2t).$$

Hence, the general solution to the non-homogeneous second-order differential equation is:

$$X(t)=x_c(t)+x_p(t)=C_1e^{-3t}+C_2te^{-3t}-\frac7{169}\cos(2t)+\frac{17}{169}\sin(2t)$$ where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants.

Comment: Please format your post using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference): this will make it much more readable.